# Azure-DevOps Run powershell Getting Error while running

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I have below command which is used for change vm size on azure:

```
Install-PackageProvider -name nuget -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
IF(!(Get-InstalledModule PSExcel -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)){
Install-Module -Name PSExcel -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force 
Import-Module PSExcel -Force
}

IF(!(Get-InstalledModule ImportExcel -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)){
Install-Module -Name ImportExcel -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force 
Import-Module ImportExcel -Force
}

IF(!(Get-InstalledModule az -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)){
Install-Module -Name az -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force 
Import-Module az -Force
}
Import-Module PSExcel -Force
Import-Module ImportExcel -Force

$ExcelFile = "D:\test-data (3).xlsx"
$objExcel = New-Excel -Path $ExcelFile  
$WorkBook = $objExcel | Get-Workbook

$NewExcelFile ="D:\test-data1.xlsx"
copy-item $ExcelFile -Destination $NewExcelFile

$sheetName = "Sheet2"
$newExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$newwb = $newExcel.Workbooks.Open($NewExcelFile)
$WorkSheet = $newwb.sheets.item($sheetName)
$WorksheetRange = $workSheet.UsedRange
$RowCount = $WorksheetRange.Rows.Count
$sheet=$newwb.Worksheets.Item(1)
$q=$RowCount
write-host 260


$q1="R"+$q 
$r1 = $sheet.Range("R2:$q1") 
$r1.cut() 
$i1="I"+$q
$r2 = $sheet.Range("I2:$i1") 
$sheet.Paste($r2)
$newwb.Close($true)
$newExcel.Quit() 

#Import-Module az -Force
#Connect-AzAccount 
Write-Host 273
#Loop through all items in the excel  
ForEach($Worksheet in @($Workbook.Worksheets)) 
{  
    $totalNoOfRecords = $Worksheet.Dimension.Rows  
    $totalNoOfItems = $totalNoOfRecords - 1  
    
    # Declaring starting positions first row and column names  
    $rowNo, $Instance_Type_Current = 1, 9  
    $rowNo, $Instance_Type_Recommended = 1, 18  
    $rowNo, $Resource_Group= 1,42 
    $rowNo, $Resource_Name = 1,2
    $rowNo, $osname = 1,8
    if ($totalNoOfRecords -gt 1) 
    {  
        #Loop to get values from excel file  
        for ($i = 1; $i -le $totalNoOfRecords - 1; $i++) 
        {  
            $newvmsize = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($rowNo + $i, $Instance_Type_Recommended).text
            $vmName    = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($rowNo + $i, $Resource_Name).text
            $resourceGroup = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($rowNo + $i, $Resource_Group).text
            $currentvmsize = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($rowNo + $i, $Instance_Type_Current).text
            $Checkwindowsos = $WorkSheet.Cells.Item($rowNo + $i, $osname).text
            $currentsizefromazure = (Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VMName $vmName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).HardwareProfile.VmSize
            
            #If only windows OS then VM size will update on azure
            IF($Checkwindowsos -match 'windows'){
            IF($currentvmsize -eq $currentsizefromazure) {
            Stop-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $vmName -Force 
            $vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -VMName $vmName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            $vm.HardwareProfile.VmSize = $newvmsize 
            Write-Host 304
            $vmstatus = $null
            while($vmstatus -notmatch 'deallocated'){
            $vmstatus=((get-azvm -Name $VmName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup  -Status).Statuses[1]).code
            }

            #Start VM Snapshot(Backup)
            $vm1 = get-azvm -Name $VmName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup 
            write-host $VmName
            $snapshotdisk = $vm1.StorageProfile 
            $vmlocation =$vm1.location
            #backup OS DISK
            $OSDiskSnapshotConfig = New-AzSnapshotConfig -SourceUri $snapshotdisk.OsDisk.ManagedDisk.id -CreateOption Copy -Location $vmlocation -OsType Windows
            $snapshotNameOS = "$($snapshotdisk.OsDisk.Name)_snapshot_$(Get-Date -Format ddMMyy)"
            New-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -SnapshotName $snapshotNameOS -Snapshot $OSDiskSnapshotConfig 
            Write-Output "VM-Name $($vm1.name) OS Disk Snapshot End & Snapshot name is $snapshotNameOS"
            Write-Host 319
            #backup Data DISK
            $dataDisks = ($snapshotdisk.DataDisks).name 
            IF($dataDisks -ne $null){
            foreach ($datadisk in $datadisks) {
                $dataDisk = Get-AzDisk -ResourceGroupName $vm1.ResourceGroupName -DiskName $datadisk
                Write-Output "VM $($vm1.name) data Disk Name $($datadisk.Name) Snapshot Begin"
                $DataDiskSnapshotConfig = New-AzSnapshotConfig -SourceUri $dataDisk.Id -CreateOption Copy -Location $vmlocation
                $snapshotNameData = "$($datadisk.name)_snapshot_$(Get-Date -Format ddMMyy)"
                New-AzSnapshot -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -SnapshotName $snapshotNameData -Snapshot $DataDiskSnapshotConfig 
                Write-Output "VM $($vm1.name) data Disk $($datadisk.Name) Snapshot End" 
             }}

            Update-AzVM -VM $vm -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            Start-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $vmName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            
            $vmstatus = $null
            while($vmstatus -notmatch 'running'){
            $vmstatus=((get-azvm -Name $VmName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup  -Status).Statuses[1]).code
            }
            Write-Host Your VM name $vmName is started and changed size from $currentvmsize changed to $newvmsize
            }
            elseif($currentsizefromazure -eq $newvmsize) { Write-host  Your VM $vmName is already Upgraded}
            else{Write-host VM current size is mismatched from azure size}
            }
        }  
    }  
}
```

Giving below error while running this script on azure devops:
Please help to resolve error.

```
Unable to get the Open property of the Workbooks class
At C:\Users\azureadmin\Downloads\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.195.2\_work\1\s\Automatic VM backup.ps1:28 char:1
+ $newwb = $newExcel.Workbooks.Open($NewExcelFile)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

**Note: Script is running on self hosted agent and this script is running when normal ISE also azconnection through devops azure**
**p.s. This script is change vm size and get backup**
[image]

Comment: as a test comment out ```Install-PackageProvider -name nuget -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force``` on a machine nuget is installed on. 
Also, both excel files open with good data ?

Comment: why are you not using ```Import-Excel``` ?
https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-excel/